# Flash is incapable of instantiating a class from the declaration section of another one?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I just want to do something trivial:

```
public class MyClass1 
{

    private var MyClass2:MyClass2 = new MyClass2();
```

And I got the ERROR

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: myClass2.

Update: My class is capitalized in real. Flash doesn't accept same name which is obsviously weird: in other languages there's no problem! Why does Flash confuse the two it's out of me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 1 of two problems here.

1. You didn't import myClass2 and it is in a different namespace (package)
2. **The more likely problem** is that you are naming your variable the same as your class, and I believe that is a no-no if I remember correctly.

---

Try:

```
private var myClassInstance:myClass2 = myClass2();
```

which should, by the way, be more like:

```
private var myClass2:MyClass2 = MyClass2();
```

since classes should be capitalized.

Comment: My class is capitalized in real. Flash doesn't accept same name which is obsviously weird: in other languages there's no problem! Why does Flash confuse the two it's out of me!